# Java - Android SDK - Unfrotunately <project name> has crashed error

Tags: java, android, sdk, crash, runtime-error

I Have been working on a small app, which can calculate complex numbers for me (division, subtraction, multiplying etc.). I have no apparent compile errors, but when i run the program I get a bunch of run-time errors which I can't understand or know how to fix. Am i missing something obvious? This is my code:

```
    package complex.OliverV;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.RadioButton;
    import android.widget.EditText;

    public class ComplexNumbersActivity extends Activity {

Button Check;
RadioButton plus, minus, multiply, div;
EditText X1,X2,Y1,Y2;
TextView Ans;
int sign;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Check = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Check);
    plus = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.plus);
    minus = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.minus);
    multiply = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.multiply);
    div = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.div);
    Ans = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Ans);
    plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            sign=1;
        }


    });
    minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            sign=2;
        }


    });
    multiply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            sign=3;
        }


    });
    div.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            sign=4;
        }


    });
    Check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        String xs=X1.getText().toString();
        String xss=X2.getText().toString();
        String ys=Y1.getText().toString();
        String yss=Y2.getText().toString();



        double x3,y3;

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(xs!="" && xss!="" && ys!="" && yss!="")
            {
            double x1=Double.parseDouble(xs);
            double x2=Double.parseDouble(xss);
            double y1=Double.parseDouble(ys);
            double y2=Double.parseDouble(yss);
            switch(sign)
            {
            case(1):
            {
                x3=x1+x2;
                y3=y1+y2;
            }
            case(2):
            {
                x3=x1-x2;
                y3=y1-y2;
            }
            case(3):
            {
                x3=(x1*x2-y1*y2);
                y3=(x2*y1 + x1*y2);
            }
            case(4):
            {
                if(x2!=0 && y2!=0)
                {
                x3 = (x1 * x2 + y1 * y2) / (x2 * x2 + y2 * y2);
                y3 = (x2 * y1 - x1 * y2) / (x2 * x2 + y2 * y2);
                }
                else
                {
                    Ans.setText("Enter valid numbers!");
                }
            }
        }
            Ans.setText("x="+x3+"y="+y3);
        }
            else
            {
                Ans.setText("Enter valid numbers!");
            }

        }
    });
}

}
```

I am also adding a screenshot of the errors I get.[image: Errors]
Im putting an image, because copying the text looks like a mess. Sorry for the long question and thank you to anyone who can take the time to help me out, I am very grateful for every bit of help. :)

Comment: that line you have selected in your screenshot (under caused by) contains the line number of where you NullPointerException is happening.  Unfortunately, it is clipped off

Comment: The important part is the "Caused by" then an exception type, followed by the stack trace.  Start at the top, then go down until you find the first line that's in your program.  This is where you have a bug.  In this case you have a NullPointerException somewhere in onCreate.  Unfortunately I can't read more because you pasted an image rather than copy pasted the text.

Comment: Compiler errors and runtime errors are totally unconnected, since you cannot get the latter without fixing the former.

Comment: sec i'll copy the text.

Comment: Also, before you setOnClickListeners,  you may want to findViewById for EditText's X1,X2,Y1,Y2;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

initialize `X1,X2,Y1,Y2` in your `onCreate()` as Ted Hopp mentioned in his answer and then

change this:

```
if(xs!="" && xss!="" && ys!="" && yss!="")
```

to:

```
if( (xs != null && !xs.equal("")) && 
    (xss != null && !xss.equal("")) && 
    (ys !== null && !ys.equal("")) && 
    (yss != null &&!yss.equal("")) )
```

Comment: thankx. and always check two string by `.equal()` instead of `== or !=` :)

Comment: only one small problem left - there are some calculating errors, could that be from the parsing or what, because it doesn't seem to be adding/subtracting etc. properly.. :\

Comment: or is it because im going via the string, instead of straight to double?

Comment: what is the error? like 2+2 should give 4 but it giving something else? or are u getting something in logcat? if you r getting something in logcat, upload the image and give me link. or if it is strange behavior, tell me what result should happen and what result u r getting

Comment: well 2+2 does not give me 4, as for the logcat it's showing some errors, but when i click clear it tells me java.lang.NullPointerException and doesn't want to clear the log of errors. Im going to bed but I'll sit down to try and tackle this tomorrow thanks for your help anyways :))

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be here:

```
Check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

    String xs=X1.getText().toString();
    String xss=X2.getText().toString();
    String ys=Y1.getText().toString();
    String yss=Y2.getText().toString();

    . . .
}
```

When this is executing inside `onCreate`, the fields `X1`, etc., have not been initialized. Even if it had, the fields would have only the default text, which is probably not what you want. You should move the assignments into the `onClick` method of the listener. That way you will be working with the current field contents when the `onClick` method runs.

In the future, please post the text of the logcat output rather than a screen snapshot. Failing that, at least resize the columns and scroll as necessary so we can see the entire text of the logcat messages. And please identify which line(s) in your code are generating the exception.

Comment: @Oliver - Also be sure to change the string equality comparisons (currently with `!=`) to `!equals()` tests, as [Shoshi suggests](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15099018/535871).