# ClassCastException: EditText to Button Error

Tags: java, android, runtime-error, classcastexception

I am working on an android app, which I had fixed after posting it here: [Java - Android SDK - Unfrotunately <project name> has crashed error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15098895/java-android-sdk-unfrotunately-project-name-has-crashed-error) and fixing the issues. Today I was messing about with the layout, because I didn't like the way it looked after which i attempted to run the program and got an error about casting a `EditText` to a `Button`, which I'm pretty sure I'm not doing. What causes the `ClassCastException`? Thank you in advance for your help.

```
  package complex.OliverV;

  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.widget.Button;
  import android.widget.TextView;
  import android.widget.RadioButton;
  import android.widget.EditText;
  public class ComplexNumbersActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
Button Check;
RadioButton plus, minus, multiply, div;
EditText X1,X2,Y1,Y2;
TextView Ans;
int sign;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Check = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Check);
    plus = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.plus);
    minus = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.minus);
    multiply = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.multiply);
    div = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.div);
    Ans = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Ans);
    X1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.X1);
    X2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.X2);
    Y1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.Y1);
    Y2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.Y2);
    plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            sign=1;
        }


    });
    minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            sign=2;
        }


    });
    multiply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            sign=3;
        }


    });
    div.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            sign=4;
        }


    });
    Check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String xs=X1.getText().toString();
            String xss=X2.getText().toString();
            String ys=Y1.getText().toString();
            String yss=Y2.getText().toString();
            double x3 = 0, y3 = 0;
            if(!xs.equals("") && !xss.equals("") && !ys.equals("") && !yss.equals("")&& xs != null && xss != null && ys != null && yss != null)
            {
            double x1=Double.parseDouble(xs);
            double x2=Double.parseDouble(xss);
            double y1=Double.parseDouble(ys);
            double y2=Double.parseDouble(yss);
            switch(sign)
            {
            case(1):
            {
                x3=x1+x2;
                y3=y1+y2;
            }
            case(2):
            {
                x3=x1-x2;
                y3=y1-y2;
            }
            case(3):
            {
                x3=(x1*x2 - y1*y2);
                y3=(x2*y1 + x1*y2);
            }
            case(4):
            {
                if(x2!=0 && y2!=0)
                {
                x3 = (x1 * x2 + y1 * y2) / (x2 * x2 + y2 * y2);
                y3 = (x2 * y1 - x1 * y2) / (x2 * x2 + y2 * y2);
                }
                else
                {
                    Ans.setText("Enter valid numbers!");
                }
            }
        }
            Ans.setText("x = "+x3+"y = "+y3);
        }
            else
            {
                Ans.setText("Enter valid numbers!");
            }
        }
    });
}       
}
```

This is the list of errors from the Logcat.

```
  02-27 21:04:48.679: E/AndroidRuntime(571): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  02-27 21:04:48.679: E/AndroidRuntime(571): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{complex.OliverV/complex.OliverV.ComplexNumbersActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.EditText cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
  02-27 21:04:48.679: E/AndroidRuntime(571):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
  02-27 21:04:48.679: E/AndroidRuntime(571):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
  02-27 21:04:48.679: E/AndroidRuntime(571):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
  02-27 21:04:48.679: E/AndroidRuntime(571):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
  02-27 21:04:48.679: E/AndroidRuntime(571):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  02-27 21:04:48.679: E/AndroidRuntime(571):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  02-27 21:04:48.679: E/AndroidRuntime(571):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
  02-27 21:04:48.679: E/AndroidRuntime(571):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  02-27 21:04:48.679: E/AndroidRuntime(571):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  02-27 21:04:48.679: E/AndroidRuntime(571):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
  02-27 21:04:48.679: E/AndroidRuntime(571):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
  02-27 21:04:48.679: E/AndroidRuntime(571):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  02-27 21:04:48.679: E/AndroidRuntime(571): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.EditText cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
  02-27 21:04:48.679: E/AndroidRuntime(571):    at complex.OliverV.ComplexNumbersActivity.onCreate(ComplexNumbersActivity.java:21)
  02-27 21:04:48.679: E/AndroidRuntime(571):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
  02-27 21:04:48.679: E/AndroidRuntime(571):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
  02-27 21:04:48.679: E/AndroidRuntime(571):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
  02-27 21:04:48.679: E/AndroidRuntime(571):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: -1 this means LITERALLY what exception said

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure that R.id.Check refers to a `Button`, then you can try cleaning your project, and building again.

Answer (score 2):

According to the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.EditText cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
    at complex.OliverV.ComplexNumbersActivity.onCreate(ComplexNumbersActivity.java:21)
```

`R.id.Check` refers to an EditText not a Button, here.

```
    Check = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Check);  // Line 21
```

Change either the Java code or the XML in `main.xml` depending on which View type you actually want.

Also please read about [Java naming convention](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm) which states that variables should start with a lowercase letter to help distinguish them from classes.

Comment: yeah sry im better with C++ and C# and havent dont much with Java and classes as a whole. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Check = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Check);
```

seems like your R.id.Check is an EditText, not a Button.

Answer (score 1):

Error is here

```
Check = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Check);
```

It is because of this

```
E/AndroidRuntime(571): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.EditText cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
```

That error says you are trying to convert an EditText which is not a button.

Go to your XML file where the related layout is designed and change the android ID value for the particular fields

**Edit**

It seems like you are coming from C++ background. In Java, please follow Java naming standards, otherwise your code will be rated as a bad design and will misguide lot of "quick look" developers.